# How to access python class attributes dynamically?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to build a User model for python. I have to insert values into a a database using SQL_Alchemy ORM. For this I have defined a class `User` which has attributes `id,first_name,second_name,last_name,email etc`. The class inherits the db.Model and the attirbutes and coloumns are mapped accordingly. The implementation of the class is given below:

```
class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Coloumn('id',db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Coloumn('first_name',db.String)
    second_name = db.Coloumn('second_name',db.String)
    last_name = db.Coloumn('last_name',db.String)
    email = db.Coloumn('email',db.String)
    password = db.Coloumn('password',db.String)
```

I want to implement a method name insert() which takes value as an argument and maps it to the class attributes dynamically.

For now I have implemented it the following way:

```
    def insert(self,first_name,second_name,last_name,email,password):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.second_name = second_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
```

I want to implement the method in such a way that dictionary values as an kwargument and maps it to the the class attributes accordingly.

For example the method should be declared as 
`insert(self,**kwargs):`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways. More verbosely:

```
def insert(self, **kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, k, v)
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
def insert(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

The latter won't work for classes whose instances don't have `__dict__`'s, like classes that define `__slots__`

Comment: The first option worked. Thanks!